# How to change text of a button and set OnClickListener within an if()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, onclicklistener

I am having a problem in that I have to spinners and two buttons in my layout and I want to change the text of the button "linjaText" and also make the onclicklistener for the button "linjaeDuhur" start another activity DEPENDING on what item is selected in the two listeners.
I have come up with one solution by giving a value to int1 and int2 depending on the spinner selections and checking them in the condition and I can display a toast but I cant seem to change the text in the button or make the other button open the other activity.
Please help!

Here is my java source code:

```
public class GjejLinjen extends Fragment {

    static Button linjaText;
    static Button kerko;
    static ImageView linjaeDuhur;
    static View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gjej_linjen, container, false);

         kerko = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.kerko);

         linjaText = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linjaText);

         linjaeDuhur = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linjaeDuhur);

        Spinner nisja = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nisja);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.lagjet, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        nisja.setAdapter(adapter1);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mberritja);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.lagjet, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        nisja.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Germi")) {
                    Stringat.int1 = 0;
                }
                else if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Sofali")) {

                    Stringat.int1 = 1;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Zgjedh Qytetin ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Germi")) {

                    Stringat.int2 = 0;



                }
                else if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Sofali")) {
                    Stringat.int2 = 1;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Zgjedh Qytetin ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        if ((Stringat.int1==0 || Stringat.int2==0)){

            kerko.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),("stringu= "+Stringat.int1+"   stringu2="+Stringat.int2+""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });

            linjaeDuhur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),("stringu= "+Stringat.int1+"   stringu2="+Stringat.int2+""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });



        }else if(Stringat.int1==1 && Stringat.int2==1){



            kerko.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),("stringu= "+Stringat.int1+"   stringu2="+Stringat.int2+""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    linjaText.setText("Linja 5");

                }
            });

            linjaeDuhur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),("stringu= "+Stringat.int1+"   stringu2="+Stringat.int2+""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    Intent i = new Intent (getActivity(), Linja.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and here is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Vendi i Nisjes"
        android:id="@+id/nisjaText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/button_material_light"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/nisja"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nisjaText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Vendi i Mberritjes"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:id="@+id/mberritjaText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nisja"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/mberritja"
        android:background="@color/primary_material_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mberritjaText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mberritja"
        android:background="#02aff1"
        android:id="@+id/kerko"
        android:text="Kerko Linjen"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kerko"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Linja e Duhur"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/linjaText" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/linjaeDuhur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/normalcall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Im really desperate so please any answer to this or any other working solution would be really appreciated.

Thanx in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this the way you have done it. The main reason for this is that you are defining your `onClickListener` in your `onCreateView` checking the values of `stringat` integers.

Implement your `onClickListener` and inside check `stringat` values as follows.

```
 kerko.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),("stringu= "+Stringat.int1+"   stringu2="+Stringat.int2+""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(Stringat.int1 == 1 && Stringat.int2 == 1)
                     linjaText.setText("Linja 5");
            }
        });

linjaeDuhur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),("stringu= "+Stringat.int1+"   stringu2="+Stringat.int2+""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(Stringat.int1 == 1 && Stringat.int2 == 1)
                {
                     Intent i = new Intent (getActivity(), Linja.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please tell me if I did not answer your question, your var names are somekind weird :D

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you Sir that did the job , and yeah its true that the variables are kind of weird cause they are in Albanian , but still your trick did the job just perfectly and now I can continue with the work,
Thanx once again ;)